# Login error: An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: firebase

I am trying to use firebase hosting to deploy my node app. On their site, they tell you to install firebase-tools through- `npm install -g firebase-tools`

It installs fine but when I try to login to firebase by- `firebase login`, it says- `Error: An unexpected error has occurred.`

I am using firebase version 3.15.0 in Windows 10.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the command with `--debug`

```
firebase login --debug
```

you using nodejs version ?

Comment: When I run that, it says- `Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
[2017-11-12T11:56:11.200Z] Error: This socket is closed`. I am using nodejs v7.1.0. Thank you!

Comment: Try Downgrade node to 6.9.1 fix it or upgrade node latest version

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today, I ran it with `--debug` and found out that I've installed npm/node as **sudo** user, running following:

```
firebase login
```

was giving me this error:

```
Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

When I ran it with sudo, I was able to deploy hosting and functions locally:

```
sudo firebase login --debug
```